# Bootstrap CSS Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a quick UI for a page and I am still in the early stages.

There is one thing I am trying to do and cant quite figure it out.

In the screenshot attached, I would like to have a full height column with a solid background color that goes from the `HR` to the `footer` on the left side.

[image]

I created a fiddle with the basic rendering of the page.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/unovgp8b/

I tried adding a class to the left column and giving it a height of 100% but that never worked. My goal is for this column (the solid background) to always be 100% height seeing how the content on the right is going to push the page down when the panel details are populated.

Is there any easy way to make a 100% height column using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a equal height column I think. There are many ways of doing this, one would be to have an outer container set to `overflow: hidden`, then add this to the left column:

```
margin-bottom: -99999px;
padding-bottom: 99999px;
```

Heaps more examples here: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h3no8jww/1/**

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and although the overflow went all the way through the footer, when i set the background color of the left column, it still cut off after the last element in the left menu.

Comment: The footer will need to be outside the container. Try adding more padding, let's say 100000px to avoid the cut off

Comment: Note: the container needs to contain both the left column as the content column so you could set the overflow on the row.

Comment: I tried adding the overflow to the row and it gets cut-off where the container ends (before the footer). Without the overflow, I see the background color going past the footer (all 9000+ pixels of it) so it seems like its something to do with the container that's causing it to be cut off